# iPhone App Rejected: first time launch the screen turns white on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, testflight

My iPhone only app got rejected, but when Apple tried it on an iPad x1/x2 the app turned white after the launch screen. I think the status bar is the problem, but I'm not sure. I have `View controller-based status bar appearance` `NO` in plist. And then on my first VC in a PageViewController I use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false`.

The app runs as it should when it's removed from memory and reopened.

Has anyone else faced the same problem?

**Edit**:

Some more info: After LaunchScreen my first ViewController is a PageViewController and in the first ViewController I open a loading ViewController while downloading some json. This looks/appears as an extension of the launch screen but with a animation of the image used in LaunchScreen, when the JSON is downloaded I remove it and my PageViewController shows.

```
self.loadingViewController = LoadingiewController()
self.loadingViewController!.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(self.loadingViewController.view)
```

**Edit2**:

So I still have the problem. It's only in the TestFlight version. I'm manipulating the status bar from Light to Default, hidden to visible.

Under Xcode/Devices live log I get this:

```
<Warning>: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13e61d790 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13e546f30]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x13e544af0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13e632b30 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13e546f30]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x13e544af0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13e61d790 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13e546f30]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x13e544af0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

**Edit3**:

So I just noticed. If I open the app newly installed from the TestFlight popup/alert window the constraint gets broken and the app goes white. But! If I open the app from the SpringBoard the first time it works. This is so strange.

Comment: Did you test the app on an iPad or on the iPad Simulator?

Comment: Are you sure that the issue occurs only on iPad and not on iPhones, an exception while initialising the app can cause a white screen. Check your app delegate once.

Comment: It runs on all simulators, the strange thing is it also runs on "my" ItunesConnect TestFlight account, but not the account I'm publishing on. And yes it's only on iPad. That is also what is specified in the rejection.

Comment: Has Apple provided a crash report?

Comment: There is none, It's not crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had `UIWindow.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Removing this line solved it.

Comment: How can you be down voting this? It's what caused the white screen and what made the app rejected on App Store.

Comment: I confirm that this is indeed the case. I've had exactly the same issue and the reason for that was whiteColor for the UIWindow