# App Rejected: iPhone app white screen on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

My app got rejected. It's an iPhone only app, but when they (Apple-review) tried it on an iPad the app turns white after launch screen. I think I located the problem to the statusbar. I have `View controller-based status bar appearance` `NO` in plist. And then on my first VC in a PageViewController I use `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false`.

Removing the app from memory and re-opening, then it works.

It's only in the TestFlight version. If I open the app newly installed from the TestFlight popup/alert window the constraint breaks and the app goes white.

But!

If I open the app from the SpringBoard the first time it works. This is so strange.

Under Xcode/Devices live log I get this when opened from TestFlight popup.:

```
<Warning>: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13e61d790 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13e546f30]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x13e544af0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13e632b30 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13e546f30]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x13e544af0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x13e61d790 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x13e546f30]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x13e544af0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for that i have also faced  same issue for my iPhone app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453820/iphone-app-rejected-first-time-launch-the-screen-turns-white-on-ipad